# Copy Table from Excel to specific Section

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I would like to copy an excel-table to a specific Section in Word. I need to Search for a String in the Header and if the Header contains the string then the script has to put a table to the Section (on the first page of Section). I tried it this way, but it doesnt work. The error says: The requested element ist not in the collection. When i try to print it he shows me the correct header. so i think the problem is the if-loop..

```
Dim Headers_text As String
Dim CountSections As Integer
Dim intSections As Integer
CountSections = wDoc.Sections.Count
For intSections = 1 To CountSections
    Headers_text = wDoc.Sections(intSections).Headers(1).Range.Text
    If InStr(Headers_text, "Part 1") Then
        Sheet_test.UsedRange.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        wDoc.Sections(intSections).Range.Paste
    End If
Next
```

Hope that someone can help me

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim s As Long
With wDoc
    For s = 1 To .Sections.Count
        With .Sections(s)
            If InStr(.Headers(1).Range.Text, "Part 1") > 0 Then
                Sheet_test.UsedRange.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
                .Range.Characters.First.Paste
            End If
        End With
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but it doesnt work. I got the same error message as before. He paste the tablepicture in my worddoc, but he deletes the whole Section, where the picture should be put in and then he paste the picture on the first page of the next Section..

Comment: «He paste the tablepicture in my worddoc, but he deletes the whole Section» That's because your own paste code would have done the same thing and you hadn't said anything about where in the Section you wanted the table pasted. Try the revised code.